# How does IDataReader define it's indexer?

Tags: c#

For some reason this code:

```
MethodInfo iDataReaderIndexerProperty = typeof(IDataReader).GetProperties()
    .Single(property => property.GetIndexParameters().Length > 0)
    .GetGetMethod();
```

fails. If I replace `IDataReader` with `IMyInterface` defined as:

```
interface IMyInterface
{
    String this[Int32 index] { get; }
}
```

it works fine. How does `IDataReader` define it's indexer?

Comment: Actually, that indexer comes from IDataRecord, not IDataReader

Comment: @MarcGravell Spot on. That calls for an answer :)

Comment: Win. This is the correct answer. If you don't mind, please post that below and I'll go ahead and mark it as correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That indexer is defined on `IDataRecord`, not `IDataReader`; so you need to query from `typeof(IDataRecord)`, **and** use Servy's observation that there are multiple overloads (`string` vs `int`).

Answer (score 6):

There are two indexers, one that takes an int an one that takes a string.  Since you're using `Single` and there are two items that match, it will throw an exception.

You have several options:

1. use `First` to get one of the two
2. use `Where` and handle both indexers as a sequence
3. add an additional constraint to ensure you just get the indexer that takes an int, and not the one that takes a string.

Comment: That's what I thought at first, but I get `Sequence contains no matching element`.